# Custom POS tagging with spacy

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

Alright so right now i have a code to do custom tagging with nltk. I use NLTK's POS tagger as a backoff with a trigram tagger where i train my own tagged sentences with custom tags. This works decently but i want to be able to do the same with spacy's POS tagger. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import string
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk.tag, nltk.data

    tagger = nltk.TrigramTagger(train_sents, backoff=nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER))

    def tagSentence(sentence):

        # Method to tag sentence according to  the tagger that is trained.
        sentence = sentence.lower()
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
        filtered_words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
        " ".join(filtered_words)
        return tagger.tag(filtered_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from spacy.en import English
oNlp = English()

oDoc = oNlp(sUnicodeInputText)

loTokens = [o for o in oDoc]
```

`loTokens` here contains a list of all tokens extracted by spacy.  Each token has properties that you can use.  To get the POS, use the `.pos_` attribute.  For example, to look at all of your lemmatized token name and POS tag associated with it in a tuple:

```
print([ (o.lemma_, o.pos_) for o in loTokens ])
```

The [spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/docs) is wonderful.  Check it out.